# error on deploy Dynamic crm 2011

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, dynamics-crm-2011

I have some trouble with deploy from Visual Studio 2010 Professional .

This is error

> Error 1   Error registering plugins and/or workflows. An unexpected
>   error occurred.   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\CRM\Microsoft.CrmDeveloperTools.CrmClient.targets 176 4   EPAM.Plugins.Deployment

I have found this file and 176 line.

```
        Deploy the Plugins and Workflows using the registration file(s)
    ============================================================        -->
<Target Name="PluginsAndWorkflowsDeploy" Condition="'@(RegisterPlugin)' != ''">
    <Message Text="WorkingFolder: $(Workingfolder)" Importance="high" />
    <RegisterPlugin                // this is 176 line
            DiscoveryServer="$(CRMDiscoveryServer)"
            Port="$(CRMDiscoveryServerPort)"
            Scheme="$(CRMDiscoveryServerScheme)"
            Organization="$(CRMOrganization)"
            Password="$(CRMUserPassword)"
            UserName="$(CRMUserName)"
            Domain="$(CRMUserDomain)"
            SolutionName="$(CRMSolutionName)"

            RegistrationFile="%(RegisterPlugin.Identity)"
            WorkingFolder="$(WorkingFolder)"
    />
</Target>
```

//if it is important: We use git as source control.

If you know something about this error please help.

Answer (score 0):

RegisterFile.crmregister file in CRMPackage project MUST be writeable. It is possibly marked as read only by git.